# Getting a matlab code's results on python

Tags: python, matlab, file-io

I have code in matlab whose results I would like to use in python code (as a matrix or as a .dat file). Could anyone tell me how this could be done?

Answer (score 3):

NumPy and SciPy can read and write MATLAB [.mat](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/techdoc/ref/save.html) files directly using [`scipy.io.loadmat`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.io.loadmat.html) and [`scipy.io.savemat`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.io.savemat.html).

Comment: I don't think so. According to the `loadmat` documentation "we do not implement the HDF5 / 7.3 interface". So I presume not - it's good that you pointed this out.

Comment: There are Python modules for reading HDF5, for example [this one](http://code.google.com/p/h5py/).

Answer (score 1):

A .dat file is just a text file:

```
fid = fopen('outputFile.dat', 'wt');
fprintf(fid, your_data_in_string_format);
fclose(fid);
```