# Converting a .dat file into an array

Tags: python

I have a .dat file generated from MATLAB (with float values). I need to convert it to an array containing the same number of rows and columns as it did in the .dat file. Could anyone suggest a way of doing this? There is a `\n` at the end of each line which I want to remove. The .dat file read into Python looks like this:

> 12,18\n42,17\n60,16\n86,17\n120,17\n137,12\n169,10\n189,14\n215,9\n248,11\n273,12\n301,17\n319,8\n345,17\n378,14\n403,10\n423,10\n453,18\n483,10\n507,15\n10,43\n43,44\n60,38\n96,41\n114,41\n139,41\n168,43\n189,40\n215,37\n248,45\n268,45\n301,37\n321,35\n

And I would like the output to be in the following format:

```
12,18
42,17
...
```

where `12,42` and `18,17` are in different columns.

Comment: Can you give some sample data? Will the number of columns differ for each row?

Comment: Presumably this is a follow up question to your previous [question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11243736/623518). If you found answers to this previous question helpful then don't forget to upvote those helpful answers and accept one of them.

Comment: @Chris: Care to explain why you changed ``12,18`` to ``12, 18`` in the output format description ? That's not the same thing.

Comment: @lqc It was an assumption on my part that the data was made up of two columns of data. I noticed that your comment suggests `,` is a decimal place (it's not here in the UK) so I have rolled back the changes. @user1482980 can you clarify this point at all?

Answer (score 1):

what do you mean by array?

```
with open('datafile','r') as f:
    rows=[map(float,L.strip().split(',')) for L in f]  # list of lists

arr=np.array(rows)  #Numpy array (assuming you `import numpy as np`)
```

Or using [numpy.loadtxt](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.loadtxt.html):

```
arr=np.loadtxt('datafilename',delimiter=',')
```

Comment: @devsundar: I've edited the post and given the sample data and the output format.

Comment: :i have an additional \n character due to which hte above code u suggested gives an error(ValueError: invalid literal for float(): 12,18)

Comment: @user1482980 -- Sorry, I didn't realize it was a `csv` file.  Updated accordingly.  (The problem wasn't the newline, it was the comma).

Comment: call loadtxt() if you use numpy

Comment: Downvoter : Care to elaborate (Or at least post an alternative so the user isn't left wondering what (s)he should do since this is apparently a bad way to do it)?

Comment: You guys do know that "," is a decimal seperator outside of US?

Comment: @lqc -- I'm aware of that (although I don't think about it often).  Anyway, in this case, it's obvious that the ',' is being used as a field separator.  He chose to store the data in a csv file, not me ;-)